# What is the difference between YARA and CLAMAV?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware

Can any one explain the difference between [YARA](https://plusvic.github.io/yara/) and [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/index.html) ? Are they just two different ways of writing AV or Malware signatures ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yara is a tool which is used to write a rule for detection of malwares whereas CLAMAV is antivirus that has predefined rulesets that is used to detect the malicious software or malware. Today there are various antivirus engines use yara rules to detect malwares. YARA provides simple and efficient way of writing rules. It is more popular because of it can be used through yara-python library. So if you want build your own malware detection framework so you can use it efficiently.

Comment: is it correct to say we can write clamav signatures in yara ?

Comment: Yes you can. Use this python script https://code.google.com/p/malwarecookbook/source/browse/trunk/3/3/clamav_to_yara.py?r=5

Comment: The earlier is used for converting clamav signatures to yara.

Comment: You can now use Yara rules in ClamAV (and not just the other way around): http://blog.clamav.net/2015/06/clamav-099b-meets-yara.html